# How do you transfer the data from a CRM 4.0 database into another CRM 4.0 database?

Tags: database, dynamics-crm, crm

Our client wants to transfer all the data in the Production CRM 4.0 database and use it in UAT.  What is the best way to transfer the data over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would copy the database.  Then use the Deployment Manager tool to import the organization (this will update the MSCRM_CONFIG database, etc.).  You may have to be careful with things like running workflows - as last I recall these might save stuff like Organization Name in their serialized state.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio
2. Right click on your source database and select Tasks/Back Up
3. Update the Destination to your desired location and click OK
4. Right click on the empty target database and choose Tasks/Restore Database
5. Select from Device and choose the file name for your backup, then click OK

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use scribe. this is considered the industry standard tool for moving CRM data around.

http://www.scribesoft.com/